# AWS Update item with list on DynamoDB using lambda Nodejs

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have an item in my DynamoDB table that looks like this:

```
{
  "qid": {
    "S": "0"
  },
  "options": {
    "L": [
      {
        "S": "Summer"
      },
      {
        "S": "Winter"
      }
    ]
  },
  "votes": {
    "L": [
      {
        "N": "11"
      },
      {
        "N": "13"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

With a lambda function, I want to update one of the elements in the votes list. I want to update the index that matches the index of the option I get from the event (the event has qid, option and number of votes). So here is what I tried:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  const qid = event.qid;
  const option = event.option;
  const vote = event.vote;
  const params = {
    TableName : 'QnV',
    Key: {
      qid: qid
    }
  }

  try {
    const data = await docClient.get(params).promise()
    const options = data.Item.options;
    const index = options.findIndex(option)
    
    const updateParams = {
        TableName: 'QnV',
        Key: {
          'qid': qid
        },
        UpdateExpression: 'set votes[:index] = :vote',
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
          ':index': index,
          ':vote': vote
          
        },
        ReturnValues: 'UPDATED_NEW'
      };
    const updateData = await docClient.update(updateParams).promise();
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(updateData)
    };
  } catch (err) {
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify(err)
    };
  }
};
```

I tried to test it with this:

```
{
  "qid": "0",
  "option": "Winter",
  "vote": 14
}
```

But I get an error of 500 and an empty body. It looks like the update params variable is empty, but I don't understand why.

I tried to search online but it looks like I'm doing everything correctly (but if that was the case I didn't have a problem). I also didn't forget to grant permission to the function.

Edit: As suggested, I change the body of the error to err.message, and got this:

```
{
  "statusCode": 500,
  "body": "\"Winter is not a function\""
}
```

Please help me find the bug, I would really appreciate it!

Thank you

Comment: try replacing  `JSON.stringify(err)`  with `err.message` and see if you get error message in body.

Comment: A 500 error, but what is the exception?

Comment: You are correct, I edit the question. I get the error: \"Winter is not a function\"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more debugging I found the problems. There were two.

1. Incorrect index method.

```js
const index = options.findIndex(option)
```

Changed to:

```js
const index = options.indexOf(option)
```

2. The way I tried to find the index in `updateParams` was incorrect. Instead of:

```js
    UpdateExpression: 'set votes[:index] = :vote',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':index': index,
      ':vote': vote
    },
```

It should be:

```js
    UpdateExpression: `set votes[${index}] = :vote`,
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':vote': {N: vote},
    },
```